# Modify ImageView (setImageResource) to ServerSocket

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to modify dynamically an ImageView (setImageResource) in ServerSocket

I used :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SocketServer server;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        server = new SocketServer(MainActivity.this);
    }
}

public class SocketServer {
    private final Context context;

public SocketServer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    new Thread(new SocketServerThread()).start();
}

private class SocketServerThread implements Runnable {
    private String read;
    private BufferedInputStream reader = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.1", 11000));

            while (true) {
                Socket socket;

                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                //On attend la demande du client
                reader = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                read = Strings.getBuffered(reader);

                ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    final ImageView ls_fp = (ImageView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.ls_fp);

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(read != "1")
                            ls_fp.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ls_fp_light);
                        else
                            ls_fp.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ls_fp);
                    }
                });


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Log.TAG.SOCKETSERVER, "SocketServerThread", e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

And this code work perfectly fine

But, when in change to another activity and i rerun activity base, the image source not change.

Could you help me ?

Comment: where did you called that code from?

Comment: this code from class runnable. And this class runnable call from MainActivitity

Comment: Can you confirm that the call from MainActivity's onResume?

Comment: no i call this class in onCreate        private SocketServer server;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 server = new SocketServer(MainActivity.this);
}

Comment: Please put your code in your post. Not in a comment. Unreadable now. You should post much more code as now we do not know what you are doing at all.

Comment: `read = Strings.getBuffered(reader);`. Nobody knows what you are doing here. And nobody can see how you would use the result for setting an image view. What is the typs of read?

Comment: You supposed to close socket connection inside activity's onStop, and resume it inside activity's onResume. If you need to keep the socket alive even if the activity is on the background, don't use an Activity, but use Service instead. And i notice a fatal error here, you should put the code for setting the image resource outside of while loop otherwise it will a big memory issue, because it will try to setImageResource inside a continuous while loop.

Comment: the socket is always alive even i change the activity. I receive all data, that work perfectly, but the image not change when i rerun the mainactivity

Comment: I wonder what that image has to do with the socket. Nothing. So why do you pretent?

Comment: everytime i receive a socket in "read", i change the imageView